# Google games sign in - error 12501 null response

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-oauth, google-play-games

I want to use google games in my app, I'm trying to make login into the google games but I always getting the error `ERROR 12501`.
I tried to login to google and I got success, but not google games.

```
GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent, 9003);

if (requestCode == 9003) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            Log.d("debug", "logged");
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();

            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = "Error" +result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
```

This is my code, I didn't change almost anything from here 
[Sign-in in Android Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin).

about my keys so I tried a lot of configurations but nothing worked.
I added this code with my app id

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="MY_APP_ID_HERE_12_DIGITS_NUM" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

[This is my OAuth2 clients ids - web, release and debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM9bx.png)

I also tried only release or only debug key but no sucsess...

[My firebase configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FvST.png)
[SHA1 I use in release Oauth2 - From google play signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWOHc.png)
[SHA1 I use in debug OAuth2 - From android studio Gradle SigningReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjtkO.png)

Please help me I'm really devastated, I think the problem is with my OAuth2 keys but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 10):

Ok so I figured it out, preaty stupid mistake but I decided to share.

So to start the **Google Games** you need 2 rows - (with your App Id 12 digit number...)

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

And you need to add them in `mainfest.xml` in `<application>` 
I added this rows in `<mainfest>` ... (**Mistake!!**)

so hope it helps someone

Comment: I have problem same with you. With 2 hours to find this bug. :(

Comment: Thank you for this. I had the same mistake which prevented me from publishing my game on android for months. Why the hell does android studio not flag this? I hope someone at google reads this.

Comment: I know this was written a while ago, but I've been struggling with this for over 2 hours and this answer only just came up in my searches, thank you, I had the tag there but in the wrong place, same as you!